# How to set an empty object vector in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, constructor

I want to create an default constructor for my object A. My problem is that one of A object`s variables is a vector array B objects.

Basically the line giving my trouble currently looks like this:

```
A(): name(""), bArray({B()}), n(0) {}
```

It must be some syntax issue.

Full constructor looks like that:

```
A(string n,  vector<B> in, int k): name(n), bArray(in), n(k) {}
```

Comment: Don't add bArray in your initializer list. If you have it as a class variable, then its already empty.

Comment: `bArray()` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to initialize the `vector` in the initializer list. Member classes are already constructed using the default constructor, which, in your case, will initialize your vector to an empty one.

Comment: Bad advice, IMHO. The initialiser list should echo the member variable declarations to avoid confusions. Scott Meyers says the same in EffC++.

Answer (score 3):

Since n and in will have their own default constructors, you don't need to explicitly initialize them. Just initialize k to 0, omit the other two and you should be fine.